# sw-precache offline mode not fetching js or css

Tags: javascript, webpack, sw-precache

Im using the sw-precache-webpack-plugin for my React progressive app, on offline mode I get the Template from cacheStorage, but its not fetching the css or js. Not sure where im going wrong.

[image]

[image]

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      cacheId: 'example-app',
      filename: 'sw.js',
      // minify: true,
      runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: '/',
        handler: 'cacheFirst',
      }],
      dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
        '/': ['./server/views/index.ejs'],
      },
    }),
```

Comment: Im having the same issue...

Comment: I had query strings for versioning on assets, I removed that and its seems to work. I need to test it on another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding below, this ignored the url parameters.

```
  ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/./],
```